# Make the first character upper case of a string in Win Form DataGridView C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

So, I have a data grid view in my C# Win Form application, the cells are editable by default, now I want whenever something is typed in those cell the end value should be treated as Upper Case First, so which means If any user types:

```
*string => String
example => Example
another => Another
chaRactEr => ChaRactEr*
```

I can do this in my code in the Cell Value Changed event, but when I do this in the Cell Value Changed event and set the value of that cell as the formatted string (Which is required from end-user) the event gets triggered twice. I can't let this happened since there is a database functionality triggering in this event.
I have tried capturing the cell value in other event like Cell Leave, Cell Enter and other events, but never can I capture it.

So I need to know, If there is a any property or characteristic of the Data Grid View in C#.NET which would make the first character of the value as upper case?
Any alternate suggestion to this would also be really helpful.

Comment: When your code in the Cell Value Changed event makes a formatting change, set a flag and skip the database code. When the second trigger comes along, detect the flag, reset the flag and execute the database code.

Comment: Another option, subclass the right classes so values are always set with upper case first. Here is the source code of DataGridView: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Have you tried to turn the `CellValueChanged` event “off” “before” you change the value (which is obviously triggering it again), the turn it back “on” “after” you change the value?

Comment: @JoelHarkes I am trying not to depend on some flag.

Comment: @JohnG do you want me to turn off/on the event by some bool flag? Or is there a default command or code to turn off/on any event?

Comment: @JoelHarkes I like your idea, I will try this.

Comment: @imcody to turn the event off/on... see my answer below. To turn the event off use... `yourDGVName.CellValueChanged -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(yourDGVName_CellValueChanged);` ... to turn it back on copy the same line and change `-=` .. to .. `+=` ... this is demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
        bool bchange = false;
        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bchange == false)
            {
                bchange = true;
                String oritext = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                String newtext= oritext.First().ToString().ToUpper() + oritext.Substring (1);
                //Update Database

                //Update cell
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = newtext;

            }
            else 
            {
                bchange = false; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. :-)
I am trying not to depend on some flag. My main query was, Is there a default property of DataGridView in .NET which would make the first character of a cell to Upper Case?

Comment: DataGridView not exist this property.
you can also use : this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellValueChanged); to disable event in CellValueChanged. 
this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellValueChanged); to enable event in CellDoubleClick or ....

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView has an event 'CellFormatting'. You can go for something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            string str = (string)e.Value;
            str = char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);
            e.Value = str;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this gets called before the CellValueChanged or after that event?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess you may be neglecting that when the code “changes” the value in the “cell” that called the `CellValueChanged` event, will obviously “fire” the `CellValueChanged` event again when its value is changed to have an upper case string!

To avoid this circular reference, simply turn the event “off” (before you change the cells value), change the cells value… the event will not fire… then turn the event back “on" after the value has changed.

Example; Below checks to see if the cell changed is in column 0, changes the string in the cell to make the first character an upper case character. The code utilizes a text box on the form that will contain text indicating when the `CellValueChanged` event is fired. If the code runs with the commented code as posted, the text box will contain two (2) entries every time a cell value in column one changes. UN-commenting the two lines of code will show the text box entry will have only one (1) entry. Sandwich the line of code that “changes” the cells value between the line of code that turns the event “off” and the line of code that turns it back “on”. Hope this makes sense.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null) {
      string currentData = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      string newData = char.ToUpper(currentData[0]) + currentData.Substring(1);
      //dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = newData;
      //dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
      textBox3.Text += "CellValueChanged fired!" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
  }
}
```